# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

Tags: dropbox

Upon trying to start dropbox, it prompts

```
$ dropbox start
Starting Dropbox...
The Dropbox daemon is not installed!
Run "dropbox start -i" to install the daemon
```

Following the instructions,

```
$ dropbox start -i
Starting Dropbox...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1443, in start
    download()
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 294, in download
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Then tried to install gi

```
$ pip install gi
Collecting gi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gi
```

The version:

```
$ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are using, how you installed it, and which partition type /usr/bin/dropbox is set on.

Comment: ty, I appended the version @Graham

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-gi` or `sudo apt-get install python3-gi`

Comment: Did you install Dropbox from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you don't have a conda environment enabled, including the root one, and run it as "sudo dropbox start -i"

Answer (score 6):

You can skip the GTK interface which will avoid loading this `gi` module. Run the dropbox script:

```
$ DISPLAY='' dropbox start -i
```

And you will get the messages in your console instead of GTK windows.